# how to separate the datagridview columns to different variables

Tags: c#, datagridview

i need some help

I am loading from my db 2 Colunmns Date is DateTime and Price is double

Date    and  Price 
12/3/15       15.00

and i store them in a datagrid.

Could you please tell me how to separate them into two different variables and Convert them to numerical in order to apply them in R.NET and make a plot?

Regards

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Connect to R
        REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
        REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();
        engine.Initialize();

        //connect to db
        string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;";//connect to server
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("Select Date,AnnualPrice from db_og.historicprices;", conDataBase);
        //MySqlDataReader myReader;
        //ArrayList DataAnnualPrice = new ArrayList();
        try
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
            DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dbdataset);
            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

            bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
            sda.Update(dbdataset);



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by separating them in two different variebles?

Comment: for instance i want to create var date and var price and somehow to to convert them into a numerical type

Comment: a grid can contain number of rows that depends on your database table data.your trying to make a variables maybe your trying to ask arraylist variables

Comment: try to look at my answer. if that help you mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property to datagridview

```
onrowdatabound="CustomGridView_RowDataBound"
```

And the event is handled as below.

```
  void CustomGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      // Convert date here
      //e.Row.Cells[0].Text = ;
      // Convert price here
      //e.Row.Cells[1].Text = ;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating ArrayList variables for date and Price something like this

```
 ArrayList varDate = new ArrayList();
 ArrayList varPrice = new ArrayList();
```

then after the dataset has been loaded to your datagridview loop through each row and add its data to the array list above.Your loop might look like this

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
{

    varDate.add(dr.Cells["Date"].Value.ToString());
    varPrice.add(dr.Cells["AnnualPrice"].Value.ToString());

}
```

Hope you get the idea and it helps you

Comment: Hi mate and thanks fro your response. VarDate and VarPrice can be used as numericals?

Comment: you may cast it according to your needs .i just give you the logic.but you can pass numerical value or string to .add method in an arraylist